# Best way to improve this MySQL request

Tags: mysql, request, long-integer

somehow I don't really like the following request which I wrote, I find it a little ugly, does anyone have a better way to write it, suggestion or comments?

```
DoSQL("SELECT A.`quotation_id`, A.`quotation_uid`, A.`quotation_ref`, A.`quotation_name`, A.`from_uid`, A.`to_uid`, A.`original_amount`, A.`direct_discount`, A.`status`,  B.`user_email`, C.`ct_first_name`, C.`ct_last_name`, C.`ct_addr_line_a`, C.`ct_addr_line_b`, C.`postal_code`, D.`account_name`, E.`name` AS `City`, F.`name` AS `Country`, H.`name` AS `Region`,
    (SELECT `user_email` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_users` WHERE `user_uniq_id` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_EMAIL`,
    (SELECT `ct_first_name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` WHERE `original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_FNAME`,
    (SELECT `ct_last_name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` WHERE `original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_LNAME`,
    (SELECT `ct_addr_line_a` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` WHERE `original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_LINE_A`,
    (SELECT `ct_addr_line_b` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` WHERE `original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_LINE_B`,
    (SELECT `postal_code` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` WHERE `original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_PS_CODE`,
    (SELECT I.`account_name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_accounts` I LEFT JOIN
                                  `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` J ON I.`account_uid` = J.`ct_account_uid` WHERE J.`original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid`) AS `REC_ACCOUNT`,
    (SELECT J.`name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` I LEFT JOIN
                          `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."citynames` J ON J.`ID` = I.`city`
     WHERE I.`original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid` AND J.`locale` = '".$_SESSION['lang']."') AS `REC_CITY`,
    (SELECT J.`name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` I LEFT JOIN
                          `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."countrynames` J ON J.`code` = I.`country`
     WHERE I.`original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid` AND J.`locale` = '".$_SESSION['lang']."') AS `REC_COUNTRY`,
    (SELECT L.`name` FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` I LEFT JOIN
                          `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."regions` J ON J.`code` = I.`ct_region` LEFT JOIN
                          `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."regions` K on K.`ID` = J.`ID` LEFT JOIN
                          `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."regionnames` L on L.`ID` = J.`ID`
     WHERE I.`original_user_uid` = A.`to_uid` AND  K.`country` = I.`country` AND  L.`locale` = '".$_SESSION['lang']."') AS `REC_REGION`
    FROM `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_jaga_quotations` A LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_users` B on B.`user_uniq_id` = A.`from_uid` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_contacts` C on B.`user_uniq_id` = C.`original_user_uid` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."miki_accounts` D on D.`account_uid` = C.`ct_account_uid` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."citynames` E ON E.`ID` = C.`city` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."countrynames` F on F.`code` = C.`country` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."regions` G on G.`code` = C.`ct_region` LEFT JOIN
    `"._MIKI_TABLE_PREF."regions` H on H.`ID` = G.`ID` WHERE A.`quotation_uid` = '".$_GET['quid']."' AND B.`user_uniq_id` = '".htmlentities($_SESSION['user_uniq_id'])."' AND E.`locale` = '".$_SESSION['lang']."' AND F.`locale` = '".$_SESSION['lang']."' AND H.`country` = C.`country` GROUP BY A.`quotation_id`;", 'get_quotation_from_info');
```

don't mind the variables I pass directly into the request, they have been verified earlier in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Build the most specific query that selects the smallest set of data and work out from that so those joins aren't horrific in performance.

Why don't you start again with the values you are filtering on, pick the Biggest table, write one query to get that smallest set of what you want.

From there, build again...   You should never be doing a query per field!

Comment: Hey Paisanco, I don't see you trying to unwind that mess, but you expect I should to undo your ban? Do you really not believe my answer is helpful?

Comment: You banned me from answering, so I think you should do it. Build those tables, write that query. Provide the proper query for his tables. You said my opinion was no good, so let's see your concrete answer Mr. ban man.

Comment: Mr. Paisanco decided this user must get a completed answer for me to not be banned. Fine. I quit. Does he do that for all questions? How much work is that? Isn't this case rather a poor example for banning just because of some commentary he disagreed with? Does Paisanco prefer that people with questions generally destined to never getting any answer continue to get no answer or commentary? Will he fill the void? Does he even know? Go back to matlab and your java. Show me who else would bother with this particular noob sql question no doubt a result of MS Access query builder?

Answer (score 0):

So you recommand to make multiple request rather than just one with sub request to get all the results?

"You should never be doing a query per field!"

I know that, however I couldn't find a better way (except multiple request) to do it.